# Create static resource with apex code

Tags: apex, static-resources, insert

Is there a way to create a `StaticResource` within a `Apex code`.

this the code i am doing:

```
        StaticResource sr = new StaticResource();
        sr.Body = file;
        sr.Name = 'testLicence';
        sr.ContentType = 'zip';
        sr.CacheControl = 'Public';

        sr.create();
```

but i am getting this error:

`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [StaticResource].create`

and when i consulted the documentation in this link:                       [StaticResource Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_staticresource.htm/)

it says that the `create()` method is supported.

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: It would be `insert sr;` from Apex code but that will not work as direct modification from Apex code is explicitly disallowed. That leaves you with having to make a web service call as Amit describes. Be very sure that this is really necessary before choosing to do it; you will be dragging a lot of code into your org.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to go with MetaData API. Something as below -

```
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
    MetadataService.StaticResource staticResource = new MetadataService.StaticResource();
    staticResource.fullName = 'MyResource';
    staticResource.contentType = 'text';
    staticResource.cacheControl = 'public';
    staticResource.content = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('Static stuff'));
    MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results = service.create(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { staticResource });
```

Remember that each create call corresponds to a callout. Here is a brilliant repository on Metadata API that can help you out.

https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how can i add `apex-mdapi` to `salesforce`. i am using a `Sandbox`.

Comment: Either download zip and deply to your sandbox or manually copy the classes from SRC and paste. it works for me in my DEV org.

Comment: @AmitBangad Do you know if it is possible to create a static resource with multiple files as content? With the above method you can create a Static Resource with a single file as content. I can't figure out how to write the content of multiple files into a single static resource with the MetadataService (or anything else) from Apex.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CreateStaticResource{
public static void createStatic(){
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
    MetadataService.StaticResource staticResource = new MetadataService.StaticResource();
    staticResource.fullName = 'MyResource';
    staticResource.contentType = 'text';
    staticResource.cacheControl = 'public';
    staticResource.content = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('Static stuff'));
    MetadataService.SaveResult[] results = service.createMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { staticResource });

}
private static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService(){ 
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
    return service;     
}}
```